# Agregar una columna de manera recursiva

Tags: r, dataframe

Tengo un dataframe, `df` que luce de la siguiente forma:

```
Fecha Colombia    Chile
------------------------
2006   9.5660    24.5576
2007  26.0079    10.9652
2008  16.0893    2.3721
2009  -5.1036   -5.0465
```

Y quiero añadir dos columnas llamadas `index_Colombia` e `index_Chile` que en la primera fila `f(1)`el valor sea 100 y el de la segunda fila para `Colombia` sea 100*(1+26.0079/100)=126.0079  y para Chile 100*(1+10.9652/100)=110.9652. En la tercera fila para Colombia el valor será: 126.0079*(1+16.0893)=146.2816 y para Chile: 110.9652*(1+2.3721)=113.5974 y así sucesivamente... de manera que obtengamos el siguiente df

```
Year Colombia    Chile    index_Colombia   index_Chile 
-------------------------------------------------------
2006   9.5660    24.5576      100            100       
2007  26.0079    10.9652   126.0079         110.9652
2008  16.0893    2.3721     146.2816         113.5974
2009  -5.1036   -5.0465     138.8159        107.864
```

Se me ocurre que se debe hacer con la función `mutate` pero no se como formularla... Pueden ayudarme?

Comment: ¡Hola! ¿Podrías detallar un poco más cuál es la relación entre las diferentes filas? Es decir, ¿hay una forma recursiva de obtener los valores? No termino de ver claro el "y así sucesivamente"

Comment: Claro que sí... en  las columnas index_Colombia e index_Chile la promera fila debe ser igual a 100, de ahí en adelante las filas deben ser la multiplicación del valor en la fila anterior por (1+valor en la columna Colombia  correspondiente a esa fila) (o en la columna Chile si es el caso). De todas formas acabé de editar mi pregunta y  está la operación para obtener los valores de la tercera fila... Ojalá me puedas ayudar!

Answer (score 1):

Este es uno de los casos en los que se no queda otra que recurrir a un clásico ciclo `for`:

```
indice_pais <- function(x) {
  
  lng <- length(x)
  rst <- rep(100, lng)
  for (i in 2:lng) {
    rst[i] <- rst[i-1]*(1+x[i]/rst[i-1]) 
  }
  rst
  
}
```

Para aplicarlo simplemente:

```
df$Index_Colombia <- indice_pais(df$Colombia)
df$Index_Chile <- indice_pais(df$Chile)
  
df
```

Revisa los resultados con los de tu ejemplo de salida por que son ligeramente distintos:

```
  Fecha Colombia   Chile Index_Colombia Index_Chile
1  2006   9.5660 24.5576       100.0000    100.0000
2  2007  26.0079 10.9652       126.0079    110.9652
3  2008  16.0893  2.3721       142.0972    113.3373
4  2009  -5.1036 -5.0465       136.9936    108.2908
```

Comment: Gracias! Sí, esto soluciona esto en particular. El problema es que el dataframe que yo proporcioné es solamente un ejemplo. De hecho, el número de países (y por lo tanto el numero de columnas) puede variar así que mi código debe funcionar de manera más general. Puedes ayudarme?

Comment: Valeria, ¿qué significa funcionar de manera más general? , por que justamente encapsular la lógica en una función permite generalizar

Comment: ¿Algo como esto: `do.call(cbind, list(df, sapply(df[, -1], indice_pais)))`?

Comment: Cuando tu añades las columnas Index_Colombia e Index_Chile de la forma en que lo sugieres lo haces porque ya sabes que el dataframe inicial solo tiene los países Chiles y Colombia. Pero en mi proceso puede que haya más o menos países (que incluyan o no a Chile y Colombuia), así que yo no puedo añadirlos de esa forma.

Comment: Ok, me imaginaba, el código de mi último comentario va en esa dirección: `do.call(cbind, list(df, sapply(df[, -1], indice_pais)))`, quitamos la fecha del calcula y aplicamos la función a todas las columnas.

Answer (score 1):

Una solución con `tidyverse`, usando programación funcional en lugar de bucles.

Son tres pasos:

Defino la función `indexador` que toma un vector `x` y regresa el índice calculado con la fórmula de la pregunta.

El corazón de esa función es un `purrr:accumulate`, que sería como una generalización de `cumsum`: toma una función que recibe dos argumentos y como primer argumento pasa el valor de la operación anterior (o el primero en el primer ciclo) y como segundo argumento el valor "presente" del vector. Para que funcione en este caso reemplazo al primer valor del vector con 100 porque ese es el inicio de la serie.

La función que paso con `accumulate()` es una lambda definida con `\()` que aplica el cálculo multiplicando el valor anterior y el valor presente + 1 /100.

Como la función se aplica a un vector la puedo usar dentro de `mutate()`. En este caso uso `across()` para seleccionar las columnas que voy a transformar y sobre todo para que cree nombres nuevos. Es cuestión de definir en el argumentos `.cols()` las columnas que quiero transformar, en este caso todas las que empiezan con "C", pero podrían ser un rango, un vector de nombres, etc.

```
library(tidyverse)

indexador <- function(x) {
x[1] <- 100
accumulate(x, \(anterior, presente) anterior * (1 + presente /100))
}


datos %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = starts_with("C"), 
                .fns = indexador, 
                .names = "{.col}_indexado"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que podrías hacer es crear una función que realice el calculo que desean en los índices.

Por ejemplo, podrías crear la siguiente función `cal_index`:

```
# Que recibe como argumento el vector que se transformará.

cal_index<-function(x){
  t<-100
  for (i in length(x)) {
    r<-100*(1+x/100) 
  }
  t<-c(t,r)
  t
}
```

Una vez creado puedes evaluarlo en cada una de tus columnas que deseas calcular los índices.

Entonces ahora se procede a calcular para cada columna. Y lo guardamos en otro data frame.

```
rr<-data.frame(index_colombia=cal_index(df$Colombia),
               index_chile=cal_index(df$Chile))
```

¿Por qué en otro data frame? Porque es necesario juntarlos una vez terminado de realizar los calculos. Y el nuevo da ta frame tiene una fila adicional.

Así que lo mejor es agregar una fila de `NAs` en tu data frame original.

```
# Agregando una fila de NAs

df[5,]<-NA
```

Ahora los juntamos con un poderoso `cbind()`

Y el resultado es el esperado.

```
cbind(df,rr)

#  Fecha Colombia   Chile index_colombia index_chile
#1  2006   9.5660 24.5576       100.0000    100.0000
#2  2007  26.0079 10.9652       109.5660    124.5576
#3  2008  16.0893  2.3721       126.0079    110.9652
#4  2009  -5.1036 -5.0465       116.0893    102.3721
#5    NA       NA      NA        94.8964     94.9535
```